# Primefaces 4.0 RC1 Terminal can't render CRLF char

Tags: jsf, primefaces, terminal

I want display the terminal response strings that contain "\r\n" (CRLF).
I expect the following code output "AAA" "BBB" in seperated line, but it always displayed in same line. the CRLF char being removed by terminal render.

I'm using primeface 4.0 RC1.

Any suggestion to solve this issue ?   thanks

```
<p:terminal id="terminal" widgetVar="term" commandHandler="#{terminalController.handleCommand}" prompt="ssh$" welcomeMessage="Welcome to SSH Terminal." />

 public class TerminalController {
   public TerminalController() {}
   public String handleCommand(String command, String[] params) {
       StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
       ret.append("AAA");
       ret.append("&#13;&#10;");  // ret.append("\n\r");
       ret.append("BBB");
       return ret.toString();
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Terminal uses html as the output, so you can break your lines using `<br>`.
Also yo can send your output inside `<pre>` html tag.

```
StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
       ret.append("<pre>AAA");
       ret.append("\r\n");  // ret.append("\n\r");
       ret.append("BBB </pre>");
       return ret.toString();
```